# WinAppDeploy - can't see device

Tags: deployment, windows-10-universal

I have a Windows 10 Universal App that shall be deployed on some Windows 10 mobile devices without using the store.
So we activated the Developer Mode, I sent the .appx and .cer files to our customers but they can't deploy them on their phones.

Then I've found the WinAppDeploy tool inside the WindowsSDK. But for some reason WinAppDeploy devices does not show any devices on some PCs. Only PCs that deployed an app via Visual Studio see the phones.

Do I need to pair them somehow with the tool? And why can some phones install the app by themselves and some can't? Just run the certificate and then the app should work, shoudn't it?

*Edit:*
Okay, now I've found out that installing VisualStudio Community with the Windows 10 Universal App feature makes me ssing the device. But what exactly was it missing?
I didn't start VS even once on this machine.

Comment: Could you please tell us your SDK version? 10240, 10586 or Insider Preview? When using the WinAppDeploy command to find the devices, did them connect to PC using USB Cable?

Comment: It was the most recent SDK, with full updated VS 2015 Update 3 + Hotfix update a few days ago. The phones are different: L735 and L650 with official Windows 10 mobile and L920 and L1320 with Release Preview. All should be 10.010586.494. I could deploy the app with no problems at all from any PC with VS installed. But installing Windows SDK didn't work out. Interesting side note: Shouldn't it work to install the app from the phone's memory? Using .cer and .appx? Developer Mode turned on it worked from my L920 and L1320, but not on customer's L735 and L650. That's how we came to use WinAppDeploy